# Connection refused to my remote server

Tags: ssh, debian, connection, webserver, sshd

I rented this server, and I had connection with it with no problems through SSH. A friend of mine suggested trying to restart the server, because it'll definitely happen in the future, and I should tackle any problem that should happen when restarting. So I was worried and not sure whether the SSH service is going to start with the computer, so I ran this command before rebooting:

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

And now I can't access the server anymore. I'm not sure whether the problem is because of that command sepcifically, but I haven't setup any firewall (I installed UFW but didn't activate it), and even the webserver is refusing connection.

The company that provided the server offers to start the server with a rescue disk. What should I do when the server starts in rescue mode?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you ask the person handling the server to have a look at the log files and possibly give you a copy of the configuration for the ssh server?

Comment: @KristerAndersson is there a specific path for those logs? Can you please give me the path so that the request can be clearer? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the specific log file but generally you would find your log files under `/var/log`, perhaps checking the system.log in that directory. If a service failed to start for some reason I guess that would be logged into system.log. You could also ask them to give you a list of running processes, using `ps -Al` from the terminal

Comment: @KristerAndersson OK, I'll try to go in rescue mode and get them myself.

Comment: Like I said you could also check if the web server is running doing something like `ps -Al | grep httpd` from the terminal.

Comment: If I remember correctly I think you also would like to check out the `/var/log/secure.log` for specific `sshd` events. You could always look at the man page for sshd: `man sshd` for more information.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Contacting the company could take a while. So I went to rescue mode and downloaded the whole "log" folder. Interestingly, there's no system.log or secure.log there. Could you please suggest something more?

Comment: Perhaps `/var/log/syslog`? You can also try searching google for location of log files in debian or something like that.